# Greater than operator not working with if statement

Tags: javascript

if statement with greater than condition returning true even though value is not greater than.

im having it return the values and it returns "no 54765>100000".
hoping someone can help me locate where my mistake is.

```
if (rev[2] > value) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =
      "no " + rev[2] + ">" + value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "yes";
  }
```

Comment: Try this: `if (parseFloat(rev[2]) > parseFloat(value)) {`.

Comment: What is `rev[2]` and what is `value`? You're probably dealing with strings rather than integers.

Comment: @JCHernández: Or rather more succinct (though possibly less obvious): `if (+rev[2] > +value)`. The unary `+` forces a conversion to `number`.

Comment: @JCHernández Put it as an answer so OP can mark it as accepted.

Comment: they were array values but i tried parseInt on them and it didnt work so i assumed that wasnt the problem, but it was i guess because parseFloat worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (parseFloat(rev[2]) > parseFloat(value)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert strings of digits into numbers with the added bonus of it working for integers and floats.
For example:

```
Number('100') // returns 100
Number('3.14') // returns 3.14
```